# I keep having an error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" in my Sign Up page

Tags: php

```
<?php

session_start();
if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])) {

    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $username = $_POST['uid'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $passwordRepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];

    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($userpasswordname) || empty($passwordRepeat) ) {
header("Location: signup.php?error=emptyfields&uid=".$username."&mail".$email);
exit();
    } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username))  {
        header("Location: signup.php?error=invalidmailuid");
        exit(); 
    }
    else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid=".$username);
        exit(); 
    }
    else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        header("Location: signup.php?error=invaliduid&mail=".$email);
        exit(); 
    }
    else if ($password !== $passwordRepeat) {
        header("Location: signup.php?error=passwordcheck&uid=".$username."&mail".$email);
        exit(); 
    }
    else {

$sql = "SELECT uidUsers FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? AND pwdUsers=?";
$statement =  mysqli_statement_init($con);
 if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($statement, $sql)) {
    header("Location: signup.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit(); 
 }
 else {
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
     mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
     $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($statement);
     if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        header("Location: signup.php?error=usertaken&mail=".$email);
        exit(); 
     }
     else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, mailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        $statement =  mysqli_statement_init($con);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($statement, $sql)) {
            header("Location: signup.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit(); 
         }
         else {
        $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $username, $email, $hashedPwd);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

            header("Location: signup.php?signup=success");
            exit(); 
         }
     }
 }
}

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
}
else {
    header("Location: signup.php");
    exit(); 
}

?>
```

As you see the "session_start();" I've added before it had an error so it has nothing to do with the error. Maybe I need to add something? Or I forgot to put something in, or I probably added something unnecessary to be in there?

Every time I refresh the page I get the error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS", what I want it to do is basically run smoothly and not engage any errors or redirects.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: There are many variables at play here. Your error means exactly that, your browser is continuously redirecting either on a single page or a couple pages redirecting to each other.

1. What is this file called?
2. What's your rewrite configuration in your .htaccess or nginx?
3. What is the result when you do `curl -I http://yoursite.com/your/problematic/path` (replace this with the actual problematic url)